# Beginner: Extension of file

Tags: javascript, php

I realize its a very basic question but I've just started so i need help with this. I've written the code in notepad using php and javascript together and I just need to know what the extension should be? Should I just save it as .html or .php or what?

Comment: Unless you've configured your server to parse .html files as PHP, then save it as a .php file

Comment: You can use any extension, just specify it in php.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must save these files with the **.php extension**.

Why?

Well, the server can be configured to parse html or other files with PHP, but **YOU** must be able to know the **content of a file without opening it**, and adding the .php extension is a really easy way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

It should be saved as **.php**.

It will also be able to accept the **html** and other **client-side** code